# How to set text to multiple textview using ButterKnife library

Tags: android, butterknife

I have more than one `textview` and I want to add text to `textview` dynamically using `Butter knife` library. I have done this thing from my side in my code but I want to know any other good way to do same thing.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @BindViews({ R.id.tv1, R.id.tv2})
    List<TextView> listTextView;  

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // must define this otherwise null pointer error show.
        ButterKnife.bind(MainActivity.this);

        listTextView.get(0).setText("First TextView ");
        listTextView.get(1).setText("Second TextView ");
    }
}
```

Comment: If there can be more than 2 textviews then you can go for `for loop`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the text content in another array say `textTitles` and then
use Butterknife's `Action` interface to set the text of each of the text view

```
static final ButterKnife.Action<TextView> SET_TEXT = new ButterKnife.Action<TextView>() {
   @Override 
   public void apply(TextView view, int index) {
       view.setText(textTitles[index]);
   }
};
```

and then finally call

```
ButterKnife.apply(listTextView, SET_TEXT);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one.

```
@BindViews({R.id.tv1, R.id.tv2, ...})
    List<TextView> listTextView;

    String names[] = {"aaa", "bbb", "ccc" ...};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(MainActivity.this);

        for (int i = 0; i < listTextView.size(); i++) {
            listTextView.get(i).setText(names[i]);
        }        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Android studio now has support for databinding out of the box. It is a mvvm pattern and official replacement for Butterknife, you may want to use it instead: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html